# Sails JS how to trigger action after automatic route POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've an application running with Sails, and I'm using a lot the blueprints for POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, and they work great.

Now, I want to trigger an action AFTER a default blueprint is triggered. For example if I request example.com/user and send that with POST, I want that the blueprint route inserts the info in the DB and then do some other action, how can I do that? To use the blueprints (which are great) and then trigger some other action, and then return.

I know that I can use my own routes, but I want to use what Sails does automatically for me, so instead of adding a route for that post and do everything myself, I want to insert with Sails and then do something else.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a bit of code to elaborate on what you plan to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I want to trigger an action AFTER a default blueprint is
>   triggered. For example if I request example.com/user and send that
>   with POST, I want that the blueprint route inserts the info in the DB
>   and then do some other action, how can I do that?

[**Lifecycle callbacks**](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) are designed to solve this kind of problem. They are functions that are automatically called before or after certain model actions. E.g. `using afterUpdate`

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 6,
      required: true,
      columnName: 'hashed_password'
    }
  },
  // Lifecycle Callbacks
  afterUpdate: function (values, cb) {
      // notify user about updated profile
  }
};
```

When you need more flexibility you have to create model actions like so

```
update: function(req, res) {
  User.update(req.body).exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) {
      // ups
    }
    return res.redirect('/something-after')
  });
}
```

And you could call another action by simply redirecting to it.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've received to a question ever, thank you! The Lifecycle callback is exactly what I was looking for.